# Observable is not asynchronous

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, rx-java

I am learning `RxJava` and am testing a scenario where I read data from a DB and then post it to a Queue. I just made a sample mock of the whole process but I don't seem to find the `Observable` working as I wanted it to ie. asynchronously.

This is my code:

```
package rxJava;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Observer;
import rx.functions.Action1;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        System.out.println("---START---");

        test.getFromDB().subscribe(new Observer<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.println("Publish complete.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                test.publishToQueue(s).subscribe(new Observer<Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Boolean b) {
                        if (b) {
                            System.out.println("Successfully published.");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable arg0) {
                    }
                });
            };
        });
        System.out.println("---END---");
    }

    public Observable<String> getFromDB() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            list.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        return Observable.from(list).doOnNext(new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String temp) {
                if (temp.contains("2")) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public Observable<Boolean> publishToQueue(String s) {

        return Observable.defer(() -> {
            try {
                if (s.contains("7")) {
                    Thread.sleep(700);
                }
                System.out.println("Published:: " + s);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Observable.just(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Suppose I get a list from the DB asynchronously and want to post it to the queue,. I have used an `Observable` returned from `getFromDB` and have subscribed to it which mimics the data I get from DB. Every time I get the data from DB , I want to push it to a queue using `publishToQueue` which also returns an `Observable`. I wanted to make the queue call also asynchronous. Now on positive acknowledgement from the queue such as the `Boolean` which I am returning (`Observable<Boolean>`), I want to print something.

So basically I just want both the processes to be asynchronous. For every data from DB, I push it to the Queue asynchronously.

I have added `Thread.sleep()` in both the methods, db call and queue so as to mimic a delay and to test the asynchronous operations. I think this is what causing the problem. But I also tried `Obseravable.delay()` but that doesn't even produce any output.

Please help me understand how this works and how I can make it work as I want it to.

Answer (score 5):

You have to specified subscribeOn value.

```
Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(/* an Observer */);
```

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html

Comment: Can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

By default, RxJava is **synchronous**. It means that everything will be perform in the same thread (and the current thread), by default. You can perform tasks in another thread thanks to `observeOn` / `subscribeOn` methods, or using some operators that perform tasks in another job (because it use another scheduler, like `delay`, `interval`, ...)

In your example, you have to explitly set in which scheduler the subscription will pe performed. (here, in which thread `Observable.from` will emit your list)

```
test.getFromDb()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe();
```

Then you can use the `flatMap` operator and calling your `publishToQueue` method. This method will be executed in the previous scheduler, but you can force it to use another scheduler, thanks to `observeOn` method. Everything after the `observeOn` method will be executed in another thread.

```
 test.fromDb()
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
     .flatMap(l -> test.publishToqueue(l))
     .subscribe();
```